# Which control action is used to deny creeps in Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

Googling for how to [deny](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Creep_control_techniques#Denying) creeps in Dota 2 will quickly let you know the magic key is "a".

However, I've had the "wasd" keys bound to move around the map. I'm trying to figure out how to bind denying to a new key. Looking in the interface however, there is no action called "Attack" as I would have expected, and I don't understand how I could then enable denying.

[image: key assignment interface].

Comment: Note that using the command "dota_force_right_click_attack 1" you can deny with right click. However you will no longer able to follow an ally (small cost to pay because I think denying with right click is way more easy)

Comment: @WizLiz Agreed; I too use the console command. As long as you have "Move" bound you can still follow an ally, and units without an attack (e.g. courier, utility wards, ancestral spirit) will still follow on right-click.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attack Move is what you're looking for, you currently have it bound to spacebar.

Comment: I'll delete my own answer and accept yours instead. I realized it shortly after posting the question. To much WC3/Dota where they are different made me fail to realize it was that simple. :)